# Python mysql.connector.connect() returns 2003 formatting error: '%-.100s:%u' (%s) %u format: a number is required, not str

Tags: python, amazon-rds, mysql-python, mysql-connector

When trying to connect to an AWS RDS server through python mysql.connector.connect(), it gives me the following error: `2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '%-.100s:%u' (%s) (Warning: %u format: a number is required, not str)`

Here's a screenshot of my terminal, you can see the connect() line where i've censored the server info:
[image: Screenshot]

Others online have suggested that combining both the domain and port number in the host arg is the issue, but as you can see in the screenshot the port is in a separate arg.
I've also verified with MySQL Workbench that the server is up and running and able to be connected to on port 3306.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This looks like a string formatting error. Are you able to share generally what your host looks like here?

Comment: @BrandonSollins It’s something like database.sjfk6diejgh2.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com

Comment: i think maybe the mysql.connector doesnt like the formatting of RDS url. can you try passing in the IP instead? and/or, maybe use sqlalchemy i believe that handles rds urls better.

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, the issue was that I had no wifi connection on my raspberry pi when i thought i did.